# Screen Freeze (Mouse Works)

Tags: mouse, freeze, amd-graphics, 20.10, gpu-driver

I was in Ubuntu 20.04 when the screen just froze, and while the mouse still worked, nothing else did.

Nothing works except starting in safe mode.  System always freezes within a few minutes.

I've tried updating to the Ubuntu 20.10 (first release beyond the latest LTR), have tried updating various drivers, am seriously eyeballing going back to Mint at this point.

**output of `lspci | grep "VGA"`**:

```
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series]
```

**Output of `sudo lshw -C display`**:

```
  *-display:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fcde0000-fcdeffff ioport:dc00(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] (Secondary)
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fcdf0000-fcdfffff
```

The last thing I tried was:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and I got the following error (which happens a lot with solutions I'm seeing proposed):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fglrx-updates
```

Many of the articles appear to be 4-6 years old, so I highly suspect their root cause is different from mine.

I'm a noob, so listing commands and what output(s) to look for to triage further would be appreciated.  Happy to get rerouted to an "already answered" link that actually works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver freezes randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224086/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-freezes-randomly)

Comment: trying the sudo apt purge nvidia-* command at the bottom, worked well until I got the following final line: 
Purging configuration files for nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.135-0ubunt
u0.16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.137ubuntu12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

About to try the second one, reboot, and get back here.

Comment: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
No drivers found for installation.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades/1164505#1164505) to fix broken packages first, then try the solution above again. If you encounter booting problems to GUI desktop, try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system/1163539#1163539) to fix that.

Comment: Well... so far that purge nvidia command alone seems to have done the trick!!!  Watching cautiously... we shall see what comes next.

Comment: Raffa, THANK YOU by the way.  I should have come here 4,5 days ago!!!

Comment: Spoke too soon.  System worked much longer, I locked screen, came back, got the white and black screens of death (I'm spanning two monitors).  Following up with your other instructions now.

Comment: Regarding your link and the sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade command: ran it, seems OK, but I DO get the following messages at the end:

Comment: W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jkist/xUbuntu_18.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG FE76CD923B7B38C4 home:jkist OBS Project <home:jkist@build.opensuse.org>
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jkist/xUbuntu_18.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Are you running Open Suse or Ubuntu? If running Ubuntu 20.10, follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305141/failed-to-fetch-security-undermined-error-ip-91-189-91-38-80-in-ubuntu-20-04/1305148#1305148) to fix your repositories list first changing every occurrence of `focal` in that answer with `groovy` then redo everything from the beginning :).

Comment: running Ubuntu, 20.10.  Tried the instructions, about to restart.

Comment: same freeze up issue; system ran for under two minutes before freezing.

Comment: Please [update](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1324263/edit) your question to show the steps you tried in the comments above so far and include the results/errors. Please also add the output of `lspci | grep "VGA"` and `sudo lshw -C display` and `cat /var/log/X*`

Comment: Tried posting the output of $ tail -n 99 /var/log/Xorg*.log but hit a character limit in this chat.

Comment: Everything related the `fglrx` driver family is deprecated and incompatible with newer Ubuntu releases since several years ago. It's irrelevant for your system, it cannot deliver any solutions any more.

Comment: looking through the DOS options, would activating SpeedStep (under Performance) improve performance,  prevent freezing?  Its currently off.

Comment: by "the DOS options" I guess you mean "the BIOS options". You need to **turn off/disable** *Secure Boot* as this might stop some modules from being loaded. We will try our best to help you, but we need more information. Paste long output [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and link to it in [your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1324263/edit). In addition to requests above, we need the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and `lsmod | grep amd` and `sudo dmesg | grep -i amd` and `apt policy xserver-xorg-video-radeon *amdgpu*`

Comment: @Raffa, thank you, here's the link:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VVZ5xgYVds/

Comment: I posted an answer below. Please follow the instructions in their order precisely and report back the result. This might be a lengthy troubleshooting process, but we'll reach a clearer understanding eventually. `display:0 UNCLAIMED` and `display:1 UNCLAIMED` might be caused by several reasons e.g. missing drivers, BIOS setting or even hardware problems. Unless we troubleshoot step by step, we can only guess.