# DIDN'T RUN SUCCESSFULLLY sudo apt -y upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

To install a new package I had to run these two commands below:

```
sudo apt -y update

sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Update1:
Output of sudo apt update

```
    Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Hit:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                             
    Hit:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                     
    Hit:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                   
    Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                
    Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
    Ign:7 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease                                                     
    Hit:8 https://repos.insights.digitalocean.com/apt/do-agent main InRelease                                                
    Hit:10 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                    
    Hit:11 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release                                                      
    Hit:9 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Fetched 114 kB in 7s (17.4 kB/s)                                                                                         
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    224 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Update1:
Output of sudo apt upgrade command

```
Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
      vlc-bin vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 libavfilter7 vlc-plugin-svg
      vlc-plugin-samba node-hosted-git-info libswresample3 vlc-plugin-qt
      php-symfony-expression-language libzmq5 python2.7-minimal
      libmagickwand-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-visualization vlc-l10n
      python2.7 vlc-plugin-notify libvlc5 libpostproc55 libvlccore9 libvlc-bin
      phpmyadmin node-tar redis-tools libavcodec58 vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc
      libavutil56 vlc-data php-twig libswscale5 libmysofa1 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
      vlc-plugin-video-splitter libpython2.7-minimal php-symfony-cache
      php-symfony-var-exporter vlc-plugin-base libpython2.7-stdlib redis-server
      imagemagick-6-common
    Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      linux-headers-5.4.0-152 linux-headers-5.4.0-152-generic linux-image-5.4.0-152-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-152-generic
      linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-152-generic
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      apparmor apport apport-gtk avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils base-files bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs
      binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu bolt bsdutils ca-certificates cloud-init cups cups-bsd cups-client
      cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc cups-server-common distro-info-data dnsutils fdisk
      firefox fonts-opensymbol fwupd fwupd-signed grub-common grub2-common iptables libapparmor1 libavahi-client3
      libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbinutils libblkid1
      libc-ares2 libcap2 libcap2-bin libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libfdisk1 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin5
      libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libiptc0 libjuh-java libjurt-java libkpathsea6
      libmount1 libncurses5 libncurses6 libncursesw5 libncursesw6 libnghttp2-14 libnss-systemd libpam-cap libpam-systemd
      libpcre3 libperl5.30 libpq5 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libraw19 libreoffice-base-core
      libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
      libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-qt5
      libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-tango
      libreoffice-writer libridl-java libsmartcols1 libsnmp-base libsnmp35 libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libsynctex2 libsystemd0
      libtinfo5 libtinfo6 libudev1 libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
      libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoloader-java libunwind8 libuuid1 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxml2 libxtables12
      linux-firmware linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-headers-virtual linux-image-generic linux-image-virtual
      linux-libc-dev linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic linux-virtual mokutil motd-news-config mount ncurses-base ncurses-bin
      ncurses-term node-json-schema openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server perl perl-base perl-modules-5.30
      php-mcrypt php7.4 php7.4-bcmath php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-curl php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd php7.4-intl
      php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-mysql php7.4-opcache 
  *
  * 
  *
  
    Get:59 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8 amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 [1625 kB]
    Get:60 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8 amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 [387 kB]
    Get:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-json amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [19.2 kB]
    Get:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-intl amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [126 kB]
    Get:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-gd amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.9 kB]
    Get:64 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-curl amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [30.9 kB]
    Get:65 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-stdlib amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 [1675 kB]
    Get:66 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8-minimal amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 [1902 kB]
    Get:67 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-minimal amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 [717 kB]
    Get:68 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 uuid-runtime amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.4 [35.4 kB]
    Get:69 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-bz2 amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [10.5 kB]
    Get:70 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-fpm amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1447 kB]
    Get:71 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-cli amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1433 kB]
    Get:72 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2023c-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [301 kB]
    Get:73 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.6 [6032 B]Get:74 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.6 [72.9 kB]
    Get:75 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.6 [1289 kB]Get:76 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt all 1:20.04.41 [5792 B]
    Get:77 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python-apt-common all 2.0.1ubuntu0.20.04.1 [16.5 kB]
    Get:78 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4-common amd64 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [647 kB]
    Get:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php7.4 all 1:7.4.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [51.4 kB]
    Get:80 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-apt amd64 2.0.1ubuntu0.20.04.1 [154 kB]
    Get:81 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:20.04.41 [9364 B]Get:82 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:20.04.41 [24.3 kB]
    Get:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-zip amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [23.7 kB]
    Get:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-xml amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [98.8 kB]
    Get:85 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:20.04.41 [105 kB]
    Get:86 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1 [152 kB]
    Get:87 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 update-notifier amd64 3.192.30.17 [56.4 kB]
    Get:88 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 update-notifier-common all 3.192.30.17 [173 kB]
    Get:89 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 distro-info-data all 0.43ubuntu1.13 [4836 B]
    Get:90 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-readline amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.6 kB]
    Get:91 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-pgsql amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [57.1 kB]
    Get:92 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-opcache amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [463 kB]
    Get:93 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpam-cap amd64 1:2.32-1ubuntu0.1 [8364 B]
    Get:94 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcap2-bin amd64 1:2.32-1ubuntu0.1 [26.2 kB]
    Get:95 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.14.4~20.04 [171 kB]Get:96 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.15 [1241 kB]
    Get:97 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.15 [581 kB]
    Get:98 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-mysql amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [121 kB]
    Get:99 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-mbstring amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [395 kB]
    Get:100 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.15 [5873 kB]
    Get:101 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-intl amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [124 kB]
    Get:102 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-gd amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.7 kB]
    Get:103 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-cli amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1480 kB]
    Get:104 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.15 [52.3 kB]
    Get:105 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.15 [87.2 kB]
    Get:106 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apparmor amd64 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.2 [502 kB]
    Get:107 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-fpm amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1490 kB]
    Get:108 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 bind9-dnsutils amd64 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.15 [134 kB]Get:109 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 bind9-libs amd64 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.15 [1108 kB]
    Get:110 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 bind9-host amd64 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.15 [43.0 kB]
    Get:111 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-dev amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [465 kB]
    Get:112 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.5 [113 kB]
    Get:113 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.5 [572 kB]
    Get:114 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-curl amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [32.9 kB]
    Get:115 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 openssh-sftp-server amd64 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.7 [51.5 kB]
    Get:116 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-cgi amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1436 kB]
    Get:117 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 openssh-server amd64 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.7 [377 kB]
    Get:118 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.7 [668 kB]
    Get:119 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 tcpdump amd64 4.9.3-4ubuntu0.2 [369 kB]
    Get:120 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-bcmath amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.5 kB]
    Get:121 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.0-common amd64 1:8.0.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [665 kB]
    Get:122 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub2-common amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.17 [590 kB]
    Get:123 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 grub-common amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.17 [1872 kB]
    Get:124 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-problem-report all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27 [11.2 kB]
    Get:125 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-apport all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27 [86.9 kB]
    Get:126 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27 [129 kB]
    Get:127 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apport-gtk all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27 [9732 B]
    Get:128 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 avahi-autoipd amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [37.8 kB]
    Get:129 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common-data amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [21.4 kB]
    Get:130 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common3 amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [21.7 kB]
    Get:131 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libavahi-core7 amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [82.0 kB]
    Get:132 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 avahi-daemon amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [61.1 kB]
    Get:133 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libavahi-client3 amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [25.5 kB]
    Get:134 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 avahi-utils amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [24.7 kB]
    Get:135 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libctf0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.6 [46.6 kB]
    Get:136 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.6 [1613 kB]
    Get:137 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.6 [473 kB]
    Get:138 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.6 [3376 B]
    Get:139 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.6 [207 kB]
    Get:140 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libctf-nobfd0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.6 [47.4 kB]
    Get:141 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 bolt amd64 0.9.1-2~ubuntu20.04.2 [143 kB]
    Get:142 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcupsimage2 amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [6216 B]
    Get:143 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-ipp-utils amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [141 kB]
    Get:144 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-core-drivers amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [28.1 kB]Get:145 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-common all 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [196 kB]
    Get:146 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-bsd amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [35.5 kB]
    Get:147 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-client amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [124 kB]
    Get:148 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-daemon amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [308 kB]
    Get:149 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [259 kB]
    Get:150 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [233 kB]
    Get:151 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-server-common all 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [403 kB]
    Get:152 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cups-ppdc amd64 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.4 [91.4 kB]
    Get:153 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 dnsutils all 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.15 [2756 B]
    Get:154 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libx11-xcb1 amd64 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.5 [9256 B]
    Get:155 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 114.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [61.0 MB]
    Get:156 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 fonts-opensymbol all 2:102.11+LibO6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [93.1 kB]
    Get:157 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 fwupd amd64 1.7.9-1~20.04.3 [2454 kB]
    Get:158 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libfwupdplugin5 amd64 1.7.9-1~20.04.3 [170 kB]
    Get:159 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libfwupd2 amd64 1.7.9-1~20.04.3 [91.9 kB]
    Get:160 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 fwupd-signed amd64 1.51.1~20.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1 [28.7 kB]
    Get:161 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libavahi-glib1 amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [7804 B]
    Get:162 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 amd64 0.7-4ubuntu7.2 [19.2 kB]
    Get:163 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libridl-java all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [196 kB]Get:164 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libjurt-java all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [105 kB]Get:165 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libjuh-java all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [57.7 kB]Get:166 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ure amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [1223 kB]
    Get:167 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libunoloader-java all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [12.4 kB]
    Get:168 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libuno-sal3 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [149 kB]
    Get:169 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [16.0 kB]
    Get:170 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libuno-cppu3 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [88.8 kB]
    Get:171 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [273 kB]
    Get:172 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 uno-libs-private amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [225 kB]
    Get:173 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [15.2 kB]
    Get:174 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libkpathsea6 amd64 2019.20190605.51237-3ubuntu0.1 [57.0 kB]
    Get:175 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libncursesw5 amd64 6.2-0ubuntu2.1 [119 kB]
    Get:176 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ncurses-term all 6.2-0ubuntu2.1 [249 kB]
    Get:177 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libncurses5 amd64 6.2-0ubuntu2.1 [96.9 kB]
    Get:178 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libtinfo5 amd64 6.2-0ubuntu2.1 [83.4 kB]
    Get:179 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.40.0-1ubuntu0.1 [78.5 kB]
    Get:180 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 12.15-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [116 kB]
    Get:181 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libraw19 amd64 0.19.5-1ubuntu1.2 [261 kB]        
    Get:182 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-calc amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [7207 kB]
    Get:183 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-draw amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [2845 kB]
    Get:184 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-gnome amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [54.6 kB]
    Get:185 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-gtk3 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [402 kB]
    Get:186 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libreoffice-qt5 amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [175 kB]
    Get:187 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-writer amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [8600 kB]
    Get:188 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-base-core amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [772 kB]
    Get:189 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-uno amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [126 kB]
    Get:190 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-math amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [402 kB]
    Get:191 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-common all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [23.5 MB]
    Get:192 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-impress amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [1073 kB]
    Get:193 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-core amd64 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [31.6 MB]
    Get:194 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-colibre all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [1181 kB]
    Get:195 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-tango all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [1248 kB]
    Get:196 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-breeze all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [2989 kB]
    Get:197 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-elementary all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [7311 kB]
    Get:198 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsnmp-base all 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.7 [206 kB]    
    Get:199 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsnmp35 amd64 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.7 [978 kB]     
    Get:200 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.3 [170 kB]         
    Get:201 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssh-gcrypt-4 amd64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.3 [202 kB]  
    Get:202 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsynctex2 amd64 2019.20190605.51237-3ubuntu0.1 [55.0 kB]
    Get:203 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libunwind8 amd64 1.2.1-9ubuntu0.1 [47.7 kB]      
    Get:204 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.187.39 [136 MB]             
    Get:205 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.4.0-152-generic amd64 5.4.0-152.169 [15.0 MB]
    Get:206 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.4.0-152-generic amd64 5.4.0-152.169 [10.5 MB]
    Get:207 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-152-generic amd64 5.4.0-152.169 [39.2 MB]
    Get:208 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 5.4.0.152.149 [1900 B]       
    Get:209 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 5.4.0.152.149 [2596 B] 
    Get:210 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-virtual amd64 5.4.0.152.149 [1876 B]       
    Get:211 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-virtual amd64 5.4.0.152.149 [2576 B] 
    Get:212 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-virtual amd64 5.4.0.152.149 [1840 B]Get:213 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-152 all 5.4.0-152.169 [11.0 MB]
    Get:214 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-152-generic amd64 5.4.0-152.169 [1362 kB]
    Get:215 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 5.4.0.152.149 [2464 B]Get:216 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-152.169 [1115 kB]     
    Get:217 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mokutil amd64 0.6.0-2~20.04.1 [26.6 kB]          
    Get:218 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 node-json-schema all 0.2.3-1+deb10u1build0.20.04.1 [7436 B]
    Get:219 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-requests all 2.22.0-2ubuntu1.1 [47.2 kB] 
    Get:220 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 python3-acme all 1.1.0-1ubuntu0.1 [29.7 kB]  
    Get:221 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 rfkill amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.4 [22.9 kB]         
    Get:222 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 shim amd64 15.7-0ubuntu1 [7152 B]                
    Get:223 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 shim-signed amd64 1.40.9+15.7-0ubuntu1 [667 kB]  
    Get:224 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.58+20.04.1 [37.9 MB]               
    Get:225 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cloud-init all 23.1.2-0ubuntu0~20.04.2 [532 kB]  
    Get:226 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc-ares2 amd64 1.15.0-1ubuntu0.3 [36.8 kB]     
    Get:227 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-ogltrans all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [8136 B]
    Get:228 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-pdfimport all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 [6344 B]
    Fetched 476 MB in 12s (40.2 MB/s)                                                                                        
    Extracting templates from packages: 100%
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    (Reading database ... 321494 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic_5.4.0-149.166_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic (5.4.0-149.166) over (5.4.0-149.166) ...
    dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
     wait for dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess failed: No child processes
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Update command executed successfully, but upgrade command didn't run fully. It get stuck in the same point every time. I have tried several solutions but every time it stops at the same point:

```
Preparing to unpack .../00-linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic_5.4.0-149.166_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic (5.4.0-149.166) over (5.4.0-149.166) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess failed: No child processes

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

My Environment is:
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

I am not a Linux professional. What steps should I take now?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt clean`  and then try updating and upgrading again. ... If this persists, then change your Ubuntu repositories mirror and try again. ... See if this helps.

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1305148/968501 for fixing repositories list.

Comment: @Raffa tried now, stuck at the same point

Comment: is this a cloud instance? if so... the correct way is to create a new instance and then attach your data disk to this new instance,

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, it's a digitalocean droplet. How can I undo changes?

Comment: Same comment: create a new instance and attach your current personal disk to this new instance. A cloud you set up with a minimal system disk with the minimal amount of changes needed and you have a personal disk where you put all your data on. Upgrading is taking this personal disk and moving it up to the new release. It is the safest upgrade path plus depending on how digital ocean this does: the fee you pay for their service is likely connected to a pre-defined container including a specific kernel (plus a few release points)

Comment: @Rinzwind now dpkg is trying to unpack linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic (5.4.0-149.166) every time when I run apt install some package command, getting me nowhere,  how can I delete all the file downloaded as part of the failed upgrade attempt

Comment: I would stop that and make a new instance and then add your data disk to that instance. If a cloud instance crashes during boot it is dead beyond repair so upgrading should never be done on a cloud instance.